System for developing Java applications and running VMs
I'm looking for a new system for me to do software development work on. My requirements are as follows:

Fast compilation of Java classes using mvnd
Fast execution of integration tests. - Fast execution of short-lived hardened VirtualBox sessions for multiple slave-OSs like Ubuntu, Windows XP, and Windows 11
At least 20 threads
Sufficient RAM. The Java takes about 2GB (JDK 22 + code + Maven = 2.8 GB +0.1 GB +0.1 GB), the VirtualBox VMs about 32gb, the SQL database about 2 GB, temp-files of about 1 GB, log-files of about 1 GB and a white-noise of 20%. This totals about 50 GB.

I'm thinking of using an Epyc Genoa 9174F; however, the retail price is pretty high (2.6k€). I found a site where I can buy the CPU for 1.6k€, but it's prefixed with "Lenovo". Will this chip work for my needs?
--
Edit: I purchased the CPU and it looks ok.


I can't vouch for "office-partner.de", but that sounds about right for a 9174F. Can you clarify why you need that exact Epyc Genoa chip? There may be a better option out there, and this site is really more suited for giving advice about what to buy rather than the validity of a specific site's pricing.

@JMY1000 I need a fast CPU and fast Storage for a application with minimal multithreading I develope. The 9174F reaches 4.4Ghz and a Ramdrive will be fast storage.

It seems like a consumer-grade chip (e.g. Ryzen with ECC RAM) might be better suited for your needs, since those have very high single-core performance with a relatively low cost. Can you clarify the performance envelope of your application, and why you think a RAM drive is necessary? Usually you should either use RAM in its normal mode, or use Optane/NAND flash.

@JMY1000 I do not need ECC ram. I need the 12-chanels. What consumer-grade chip has 12-chanels? What is a performance envelope?

Hm yeah if you need 12 channels you'll want Epyc. That said, are you sure you need that much memory bandwidth? What kind of throughput are you expecting on your application? If you can give us more details about your application and how it performs, we can help you better.

@JMY1000 I develop only, it must be unrealistic as fast as possible.

Sorry, I’m not sure what that means. There’s a lot of different kinds of fast when it comes to computers; what computer is best will depend on what exactly you’re doing with it. Could you please provide some more details about what your application does, and what kind of resources it needs?

@JMY1000 I need a fast compilation of java classes using mvnd, I need a fast execution of integration-tests. I need a fast execution of short-lifed hardened virtualbox sessions for multiple slave-os like ubuntu, windowsxp, win11. The maximum multithreading I am need is 20 threads. The java-part take a space of about 2GB (jdk22+sourcecode+maven=2.8gb+0.1gb+0.1gb), the virtualbox vms about 32gb, the sql-database about 2gb, temp-files of about 1gb, log-files of about 1gb and a white-noise of 20%. This makes a'bout 50gb of ramdrive requirement. 50gb match the 96gb ram I have on the ryzen (8gbx12).

Gotcha. IMO it sound like your main issue is CPU perf, available cores/threads, and RAM capacity less so than maximum bandwidth. While Epyc Genoa would definitely work well, I think you could totally get away with a normal high-end Ryzen 9: 16 cores/32 threads and 128 GB of RAM should still be sufficient for your purposes.

The reason I closed the question was because your original question was what we call an XY problem: rather than asking about the situation you were trying to solve, you asked about a potential solution. This made it very difficult to understand why you were doing what you did. Now that I have that information, I can edit it into your post and reopen it.

One thing to consider: upon doing some more research, Epyc Genoa can be "vendor locked" to a particular motherboard by burning fuses. This process is irreversible. This means that the "Lenovo" chip will only work in Lenovo systems, even though the underlying silicon is the same. If your motherboard is a Lenovo motherboard, great, no problem. However, if it's not, the chip will refuse to turn on. It's stupid, but important to be aware of. What motherboard are you planning on placing this chip in? Also, what's your overall budget for the system?

@JMY1000 Your last comment is a potential answer. I do not think you had to close the question for that answer.

The CPU does not work with the Mainboard I bought (k14pa-u12).  I am pretty sure the CPU is vendor-locked.  I followed the instructions from the manual 100%.  Everything looks fine but the System does not boot.

If it didnt work, then this not an answer.

@RohitGupta "Will this chip work for my needs?" -> "No, it does not work!". It is a perfect answer to the question.
